# Is it possible to use the backreference of match result as a match of another capture group?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regexp-replace, backreference

I have the following string fragments where I want to match the contents of the `key` attribute and replace all it's occurrences with `***`:

```
name="prefix1 - key_string suffix1" displayName="prefix1 - key_string suffix2" key="key_string" name2="prefix2 - key_string suffix1" desc="prefix1 - key_string suffix1"
```

I can easily match the attribute value `key_string` with something like `(?<=key=")\b([^"]+)` and replace it with `***` so it will read like `key="***"`, but can't seem to figure out how to replace other `key_string` occurrences using backreference.

Is it possible or do I need to split this into 2 regex passes: 1 to get the match result and another to replace the occurrences of match result?

Comment: What you ask may be feasible, though can you share a link with your attempt using regex101.com?

Comment: If you mean you need to find a string between `"`s after `key=` and then replace all occurrences of it in the string, better do it with two steps.

Comment: @lemon https://regex101.com/r/dGmSEV/1 - even this one can't match `name2` & `desc` values

Comment: how do you know whether a key is a key? From what I understand, you want to match `key`, `name2` and `desc`, but why not `name`, `displayName`? Are keys always find after the key `"*key*"`? @sjlewis.

Comment: There is no way to use a single regex for this. You need to use a two-step approach.

Comment: @lemon The key is the value inside the `key` attribute, ie. `key="this_is_the_key"`. The key can also appear as part of `name`, `name2`, `desc`, & `displayName`. `key` attribute appears after `name` & `displayName` attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to find a string between double quotes after `key=` string and then replace all occurrences of the found match in the whole input string using a single `Regex.Replace` operation.

This would imply saving the value to some buffer, then *seek* to the string beginning point and re-scan the whole input string. This is not possible since regular expression engine searches from left to right (by default) or from right to left (with the `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` option) but never allows to *re-wind* to the string start scan position.

The closest pattern would be `(?<=key=\"([^\"]+)\".*)\1|(?=.*key=\"([^\"]+)\".*)\2` (see [its demo online](https://regex101.com/r/TtIeBb/2)) **but** it is useless as the found match will remain, as it is the "pivot" for all matches (if it is removed before, the lookarounds will not match, and it cannot be remove later as the regex index will be long past the match).

So, use a two-step approach like

```cs
var match = Regex.Match(text, @"\bkey=""([^""]+)""")?.Groups[1].Value;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(match)
{
    sentence = sentence.Replace(match, ""); // If you just want to remove the found match anywhere inside the string
}
```